# How to align buttons horizontally under variable text in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

How do you align buttons under a variable piece of text in Bootstrap 3? If you run the code example full screen you will see that the three buttons do not align horizontally.

#### Current Behavior:

[image]

I would like the three blue buttons to align horizontally.

- Further, in Xs, and Sm scaling it would be fabulous to have the buttons be centred as opposed to left aligned. I do not want to have to resort to using `<br>` spacers.

How do I fix this? All help and advice gratefully received.

#### Expected Result:

[image]

### Current Behavior: Code Example (Hit Expand Snippet)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">View Details &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>sociis penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>Morbi penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I removed the offending reference

Comment: You need to add some custom CSS for this as bootstrap does not provide the exact solution in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @SahilDhir An example solution would be appreciated - chuckle.

Comment: you need to assign min height for p tag same as max paragraph height in my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used 2 custom classes to the already made HTML structure.\

1. **three-section** class to the parent div
2. **text-sm-center** class to the button parent div.

**Here is the solution list:**

> Solution for Button alignment:

Give min-height to the paragraph according to your longest paragraph.

```
.three-section p {
    min-height: 160px
  }
```

> Solution for button to be center aligned in xs and sm:

Write a media query with class name **text-sm-center** to be applied on your button code div and also making the paragraph height auto to make it not follow the min-height given earlier.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  // Align text to center.
  .text-sm-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .three-section p {
    min-height: inherit;
  }
}
```

```css
.three-section p {
  min-height: 160px
}

@media (max-width: 1260px) {
  .three-section p {
  min-height: 200px
}
}

@media (max-width: 962px) {
  .three-section p {
    min-height: inherit;
  }
  .text-sm-center {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="three-section">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div class="text-sm-center">
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">View Details &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>sociis penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur.</p>
      <div class="text-sm-center">
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>Morbi penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div class="text-sm-center">
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The example you provided does not exhibit the expected behaviour. I have added a visual of the expected behaviour to the question.

Comment: The behavior is exactly as you need. Check this on full page as the code is working properly for bigger screen size

Comment: Thanks it is very close but if you open Safari in Develop, Responsive Design mode and look at iPad Pro 10.5" in the Horizontal mode you will note the buttons are not aligned.

Comment: Note I do appreciate your help here.

Comment: I have added new css codes now it will work perfectly ;)

Comment: Sahil - Thankyou for your help here. Good karma flying your way.

Answer (score 0):

Add min-height to the corresponding `p` element.

Try this

```css
p{min-height:160px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">View Details &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>sociis penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>Morbi penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately the example you provided does not exhibit the expected behaviour across all screen scenarios. On the Ipad Pro the button is misaligned. I have added a visual of the expected behaviour to the question across a set of devices.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-md-4
{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height:20em;
}

.col-md-4 > p
{
    flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">View Details &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>sociis penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3><b>Morbi penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The example you provided does not exhibit the expected behaviour. I have added a visual of the expected behaviour to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some solution for your query.
some adjustment in class and css

```css
.row-eq-height {
      display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col-eq-height{display:flex;flex-flow: column;}
.mt-auto{margin-top:auto;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-eq-height">
      <h3><b>penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div class="mt-auto">
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">View Details &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-eq-height">
      <h3><b>sociis penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur.</p>
      <div class="mt-auto">
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-eq-height">
      <h3><b>Morbi penatibus</b></h3>
      <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac,
        vestibulum at eros. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <div class="mt-auto">
        <a href="#" class="align-self-end btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">VIEW DETAILS &gt;&gt;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ajay - this is very, very close. Thank you. One issue is when I go into Safari Responsive Developer mode and Select IPad (9.7") the third column wraps below the first two.

Safari - Select Develop (Top level Menu) -> Responsive Design Mode. Click on Ipad 9.7" from vidual menu.